# Get ids of elements in a named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, named-scope

In ruby on rails, all `has_many :widgets` methods generate both a `object.widgets` method and an `object.widget_ids` method.

The latter method is very useful because it bypasses the creation of ActiveRecord objects and runs a much faster query. The query speed can be improved by using the `:select` option, but ruby still allocates much more memory when generating objects instead of integers.

For example

```
User has_many :historical_sessions:

>> Benchmark.measure { User.find(4).historical_sessions.map(&:id) }
HistoricalSession Load (131.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `historical_sessions` WHERE (`historical_sessions`.user_id = 4)
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0xbe805c0 @cutime=0.0, @label="", @total=1.996, @stime=0.0150000000000006, @real=2.09599995613098, @utime=1.981, @cstime=0.0>
(2.1 seconds)

>> Benchmark.measure { User.find(4).historical_session_ids }
HistoricalSession Load (34.0ms)   SELECT `historical_sessions`.id FROM `historical_sessions` WHERE (`historical_sessions`.user_id = 4)
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x11e6cd94 @cutime=0.0, @label="", @total=1.529, @stime=0.032, @real=1.55099987983704, @utime=1.497, @cstime=0.0>
(1.6 seconds)
```

(The result set is 67353 objects)

Is there a way to have the same behavior occur when using named_scopes?

For example,

```
User named_scope :recent
User.recent (Exists)
User.recent_ids (Does not exist)
```

The way I currently get the ids of objects in a named scope result set is:
HistoricalSession.recent.map(&:id). This is essentially similar to what is done in the latter example above, and is obviously not efficient. I do not want to build entire HistoricalSession objects when in the end all I need is an array of ids.

An alternate implementation could be a new .find method. For example, HistoricalSession.recent.find_attributes(:id). This method would replace the select statement to only select the specified values and would short circuit ActiveRecord object creation to just return an array.

Any suggestions? Might this be a simple plugin to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I originally asked this question, Rails added both the .ids, and .pluck methods in the Calculations module. These would have solved my problem at the time.

pluck: [https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/activerecord/4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord::Calculations##pluck](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/activerecord/4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord%3a%3aCalculations##pluck)

ids: [https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/activerecord/4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord::Calculations##ids](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/activerecord/4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord%3a%3aCalculations##ids)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating an additional method, you could perhaps create a method on the association proxy called 'ids' so that you could do e.g. this:

```
User.named_scope :recent, ...
User.named_scope :admin, ...
User.recent.admin.ids
```

And yeah, that sounds like a sensible plugin to me. Shouldn't be too hard to write.

Answer (score 0):

Just to take a different view here - why are you bothered about this? How much memory are you using? It looks like you're trying to optimise something - but if there are only a few rows (i.e. less than a few hundred) - I can't see why you're getting worked up about this.

Do you have a problem, or are you imagining one?

Don't forget: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

:-D